# $\int_0^\infty |f(x)|dx < \infty \implies \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^xf(y)e^{-a(x-y)}dy = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For every Lebesgue integrable function $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, i.e., $\int_0^\infty |f(x)|dx < \infty$, does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^xf(y)e^{-a(x-y)}dy = 0$ hold?
If so, how can we prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true if $a \leq 0$. If $a>0$ the the integrand is dominated by $|f|$ and tends to $0$ pointwise and hence the integral tends to $0$ by DCT.

Comment: I forgot to mention $a>0$. Sorry for that. Would you explain a bit more about the case $a>0$?

Comment: Write the integral as $\int_0^{\infty} I_{(0,x)} f(y)e^{-a(x-y)}dy$. Since $y \leq x$ we have $e^{-a(x-y)} \leq 1$. Thus the integrand is less than or equal to $|f(y)|$ which is given to be integrable. For each $y$ the integrand tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. So we can apply DCT.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much for your help.